# Get a list of power of two until N in prolog

Tags: prolog

How can I get a list of power of two until N in prolog. Such that if I write func(5,L) I will get L = [2,4,8,16,32].
This is what I do, but result is not good. Can you help me correct my code and explain what is the problem.

```
func(N,L):- helpstwo(N,R), reverse(R, L).
helpstwo(1,[2]):- !.
helpstwo(N,[H|[H1,T]]):- N1 is N-1, helpstwo(N1,[H1|T]), H is H1*2.
```

This is what I get

```
L = [[8, [4, [2, []]]], 16, 32]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
powers_of_2(Len, Lst) :-
    % Conveniently avoids having to keep an element count
    length(Lst, Len),
    powers_of_2_(Lst, 1).
    
% Reached end of list when Tail is empty
powers_of_2_([], _).
powers_of_2_([H|T], N) :-
    % Simply multiply the previous number by 2
    H is N * 2,
    powers_of_2_(T, H).
```

This is nicely performant - e.g. in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(powers_of_2(50_000, L)).
% 100,005 inferences, 0.434 CPU in 0.465 seconds (93% CPU, 230470 Lips)
L = [2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple 1-liner:

```
powers_of_2(N , Ps ) :- findall( P , ( between(0,N,E), P is 2^E ) , Ps ) .
```